# R function like amatch() but replaces

Tags: r, replace, matching

Suppose I have a vector of possibly misspelled strings like:

```
x <- c("Starr Wars","Lorde of the Ring", "The Habit")
```

And I also have a dictionary vector, like this:

```
y <- c("Star Wars", "The Lord of the Rings", "The Hobbit")
```

amatch almost does what I am want:

```
amatch(x,y,maxDist=6)
[1] 1 2 3
```

It tells me the indices, that the first string in x is closed to the first string in y.  What I am looking for would be a function that would return a vector of the actual most closely matched string, rather than the index.  In other words, for a function that does this:

```
function(x,y,maxDist=n)
[1] "Star Wars" "The Lord of the Rings" "The Hobbit"
```

Answer (score 2):

This feels a bit too easy, but here it is. All you need to do is to use your amatch code to 'filter' (ie: subset) the vector with the correct names in it.

```
require(stringdist)
x <- c("Starr Wars","Lorde of the Ring", "The Habit")
y <- c("Star Wars", "The Lord of the Rings", "The Hobbit")
y[amatch(x, y, maxDist = 6)]
# [1] "Star Wars"             "The Lord of the Rings" "The Hobbit"
```

Comment: I must say, that is exactly what I was after.  Thank you very much.